# Over-Current condition on port 7 or 8

Tags: usb

I am having a problem with my USB ports. It shows over-current conditions on ports 7 and 8. I have heard that this is caused by a damaged USB port, and since it is detecting it on two ports it seems that I have two that are broken. I do indeed have two that do not work, so that is not the issue.

What I would like to do is disable whatever program is running over-current condition checks. tty's are unusable at this point. Every few second a new over-current condition occurs.

Here is the output of dmesg: http://pastebin.com/CuFKRGue

Is there an easy way to disable these checks or damage the ports to a point where it will no longer check? Fixing them is not important or an option.

Comment: If it's the USB ports, the best fix is to unplug the offending ports from the motherboard, which is often possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the following kernel option and see if it helps -- it tells the USB driver to ignore overcurrent (OC) alerts. *This is only for USB 2.0* ports -- it will not work for USB 3.0, or USB 1.0 (unlikely if your computer was made after 2001 or so).

`ehci_hcd.ignore_OC=1`

Edit `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` in `/etc/default/grub` to include this option and run `sudo update-grub`

Reboot and see; if it doesn't work, please pastebin *full* `dmesg`.

Comment: I know for sure that this will not work as the broken ports are USB 3.0. I should have mentioned that in my original question, but I figured since it's the current standard I could exclude it. I am going to go ahead and accept your answer since it DOES answer somebody who has this question with a USB 2.0 port.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the exact fix for it, because it's most probably a hardware issue. But, workaround or for logging of the error, you could unbind the port, creating the problem.
The steps are as follows:

```
cd /sys/bus/usb/drivers 
ls (There will be usb driver listed, which is creating the problem)
echo "usb_creating_problem" | sudo tee unbind
```

This ought to stop the message to be logged, as the driver for that port would not be found by the machine. Just when you get your port  fix, bind it again by:

```
echo "usb_creating_problem" | sudo tee bind
```

Also, in the above answer use ignore_oc ("oc" in small letters).