# over-current issue with USB 2.0 ports

Tags: 14.04, usb, shutdown

My system (on Ubuntu 14.04) is no longer shutting down/restarting/suspending since a problem with all usb 2.0 ports occurred. (all of a sudden all usb 2.0 were without power.
Luckily, the usb 3.0 ports are still working) 
In fact, the system stays stuck on "over-current condition on port 1 and 2" which is very annoying since only prolonged pushing on the power button can shutdown the notebook.

```
dmesg : 
[  282.314980] hub 2-1:1.0: over-current condition on port 2
[  282.522964] hub 2-1:1.0: over-current condition on port 1
........
```

I already tried adding `ehci_hcd.ignore_OC=1` to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` in `/etc/default/grub` but this is of no use. I just want it to ignore any faults so that it can shutdown or reboot.

Comment: Same issue, but, for me the message only appears while booting without causing problems. However I would like to find the reason.

Comment: This gives me an error when trying to update grub: 
'/usr/sbin/grub-mkconfig: 11: /etc/default/grub: ehci_hcd.ignore_OC=1: not found'

Next to GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT I have "quite splash". 
Also I think this usb warning a kind of BUG, becouse with Windows or Ubuntu 12.04 I have no problems.

Comment: Hello Erwin did you find any solution for this warning?

Comment: Might be a duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/147555/over-current-condition-on-port-7-or-8